# I2C Communication between DA14580 and SHT25

Tags: bluetooth, communication, i2c

I try to read out the relative humidity/temperature data from the SHT25 (Sensirion) via i2c. I want to evaluate the data on my smartphone. I have the DA14580 (Dialog Semiconductor) for Bluetooth Low Energy and communication interface for the sensor.

When i send a specific command via BLE to the DA14580 i want it to send the command for measuring to the SHT25. After measuring i want to read the data from the sensor(12/14bit resolution, 2 bytes as values to read out).  The following scheme shows the communication sequence i need to get the SHT25 working. At first sending a command for measuring. After that a read-request and receiving 1 byte, ACK, another byte, ACK.

[I2C Com-Sequence SHT25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPwi0.png)

My problem is, the DA14580 only provides code for communication with an EEPROM via I2C and i can't read out data. (I'm not even sure if i can send data properly..).

```
uint8_t i2c_eeprom_read_byte(uint32_t address)
{
    i2c_wait_until_eeprom_ready();
    i2c_send_address(address);  

    WAIT_WHILE_I2C_FIFO_IS_FULL();                  // Wait if Tx FIFO is full
    SEND_I2C_COMMAND(0x0100);                       // Set R/W bit to 1 (read access)
    WAIT_UNTIL_I2C_FIFO_IS_EMPTY();                 // Wait until I2C Tx FIFO empty
    WAIT_FOR_RECEIVED_BYTE();                       // Wait for received data
    return (0xFF & GetWord16(I2C_DATA_CMD_REG));    // Get received byte
}
```

That's the code provided to read one single byte. Even if i just want only one byte it get's stuck in `WAIT_FOR_RECEIVED_BYTE()` which is a makro to read out the received data ( `#define SEND_I2C_COMMAND(X) SetWord16(I2C_DATA_CMD_REG, (X))` I have triggered measurment before in my code with the command so its value should be available. I don't have a logic analyzer to look what's going on on the bus but i can't see what's wrong.

Any ideas how i can check that? Or what i can try else? I tried to communicate with the SHT25 via Arduino Uno and it worked fine. It's not the sensors fault.

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask in the support forum at https://support.dialog-semiconductor.com. Have you set up all parameters correctly? (PIN configuration, i2c address etc.)?

Comment: I have asked the support. I've been told to use a logic analyzer for testing the communication sequence. I hoped someone has another idea because i don't have something like that. Tomorrow i'll try it with an oscilloscope to see if i can get something similar. Maybe i'll see if it's working. 

Parameters have been set to input_pullup (for internal pullups) but also tested with external pullups (input) like it's done in the i2c peripheral example code. I don't have problems with the powersupply of the sensor. I hope i'll see what's going on tomorrow.